# deploy db on azure from bak from sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am working on deploying an asp.net website in azure. I have a database (SQL) from my development server that I need to deploy in azure db.

But I don't find any options to using which I can dump my whole db including schema and all data, sp, etc. to azure db.

I tried to find this on google but it says that first create backup from azure db and then use it. But I need to use the db that I have on my dev sql server!

Can anyone point me in right direction on how to do this on azure?

Answer (score 0):

This is the tool I use when i want to move a database from local to azure

https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Keep in mind that the azure database is not 100% compatible with sql server.  You might have to modify your database before you can really move it to azure successfully. The tool above can also help a bit on that part.